# Rails ActiveRecord Model not updating in RSpec model spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

This is driving me insane. I've stripped this down to the bare minimum without losing context (I think!)

All I am trying to do is check that when I update a value and save it to the database, that the value was saved. I want to do this because I need to write some other code that conditionally prevents this in the before_save callback, and I can't test that until I'm sure this is working!

The factories and the spec are below, I'm sure its something really stupid but I just can't figure it out...

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :programme do
    name 'Trainee Programme'
  end

  factory :membership do
    programme
  end

  factory :specialty do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Specialty #{n}" }
  end

  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "factorygirl-user-#{n}@remailer.org" }
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
    factory :trainee, class: User do
      sequence(:email) { |n| "factorygirl-trainee-#{n}@remailer.org" }
      name 'Factory Girl Trainee'
      after(:create) do |user|
        FactoryGirl.create(:membership, user: user, start_date: 1.day.ago)
      end
    end
  end

end

describe Membership do

  let(:trainee) { FactoryGirl.create(:trainee) }

  it 'sets specialty' do
    puts trainee.current_membership.inspect
    trainee.current_membership.specialty = specialty
    puts trainee.current_membership.inspect
    trainee.current_membership.save!
    puts trainee.current_membership.inspect
    expect(trainee.current_membership.specialty).to eq(specialty)      
  end

end
```

The spec is failing because the expect sees a nil value. When I run the code the debug output I get is:

```
#<Membership id: 11, user_id: 11, programme_id: 11, start_date: "2015-03-10", end_date: nil, created_at: "2015-03-11 22:02:51", updated_at: "2015-03-11 22:02:51", options: {}, specialty_id: nil, membership_type_id: nil>
#<Membership id: 11, user_id: 11, programme_id: 11, start_date: "2015-03-10", end_date: nil, created_at: "2015-03-11 22:02:51", updated_at: "2015-03-11 22:02:51", options: {}, specialty_id: nil, membership_type_id: nil>
#<Membership id: 11, user_id: 11, programme_id: 11, start_date: "2015-03-10", end_date: nil, created_at: "2015-03-11 22:02:51", updated_at: "2015-03-11 22:02:51", options: {}, specialty_id: nil, membership_type_id: nil>
```

So its as if the assignment of specialty never happens??

Comment: Where is `speciality` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to BroiState and Mori giving me some pointers I was able to establish that it was related to persistence (in particular one of my object methods not respecting it!)

The code for trainee.current_membership is as follows:

```
def current_membership
  return unless memberships.current.any?
  memberships.current.first
end
```

which uses these related scopes in Membership...

```
scope :started, -> { self.where("#{table_name}.#{_start_field}::TIMESTAMP < '#{Time.now}'") }
scope :not_ended, -> { self.where("#{table_name}.#{_end_field} IS NULL OR #{table_name}.#{_end_field}::TIMESTAMP > '#{Time.now}'") }
scope :current, -> { self.started.not_ended }
```

So each call to trainee.current_membership was giving me a new instance of the 'current' membership record

by explicitly using the same object the spec passed fine, i.e.:

```
it 'sets specialty' do
  membership = trainee.current_membership
  membership.specialty = specialty
  membership.save!
  expect(membership.specialty).to eq(specialty.reload)      
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Try reloading `trainee`, e.g.

```
expect(trainee.reload.current_membership.specialty).to eq(specialty)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer by making sure all the objects were instantiated as per BroisState's suggestion then doing reload I realised what the problem was... have posted an answer detailing (of course it was my fault!)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could think of is that `speciality` is a new, non-persisted record. Since `membership belongs_to :speciality` and `membership` is already persisted, it will not save associated object neither on assignment nor on save. In short, make sure that `speciality` is saved before creating association.

Comment: thanks for the pointer - I made sure all the objects were created with FactoryGirl.create before hand which in conjunction with Mori's suggestion helped me figure out what it was